# Npm install removes npm directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running node.js 8.9.4 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to install the 'connect' module because I need it for a project. It's definitely not installed yet, because if I try to require it, I'm told that it can't find 'connect'.

But when I type `npm install connect`, the first time, it seems to work but has quite a few warnings and seems to remove a lot of packages. It says:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.

+ connect@3.6.6
added 9 packages, removed 473 packages and moved 3 packages in 3.991s
```

(Not sure why it's removing 473 packages, might be related). Anyway, it seems like maybe it worked, and then I realize that in nodejs/node_modules, the npm directory is nowhere to be found. And now, if I try to install any packages, it gives me a bunch of errors, basically telling me:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

Connect has been installed, but at a cost that seems...not quite right (I can't install any more packages!) Obviously I'm new to node.js, please send help. And I hope that I don't get banned from asking questions again because I'm pretty clueless. Did the best I could to be specific.

Comment: Do you have a package.json in your project folder?

Answer (score 1):

It seems trying `npm install` in uninitialized npm package directory.
You should initialize package with `npm init`.

You can find out more https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json